# Using HttpClient with Windows-1252 encoded url

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, httpclient

I'm trying to communicate with a very simple web API using a System.Net.HttpClient. This API client has a search function where I can search for a user by his name. The problem is that the API is using the Windows 1252 encoding in the url and when I try to use the Windows 1252 encoded url with the HttpClient, the HttpClient encodes the url using utf-8 before making the request.

```
string name = "Arnar Aðalsteinsson"; // My name, note the 'ð' character
string encodedName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
string url = string.Format("http://website.com/find?name={0}", encodedName);

// url = http://website.com/find?name=Arnar+A%f0dalsteinsson

string result = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url)
// result = "Name A%f0dalsteinsson is unknown", actual output from API service
// httpClient encodes the previously encoded parameter to A%25f0dalsteinsson
```

When I use the encoded address (http://website.com/find?name=Arnar+A%f0dalsteinsson) in browser it works fine.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could not find the problem when try to reproduce this,it works fine on my side, try use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see your request result,could be problem from your server side.

here is my code:

```
string name = "Arnar Aðalsteinsson"; 
        string encodedName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
        string url = string.Format("http://website.com/find?name={0}", encodedName);

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
            **string result = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;**

        }
        catch (System.AggregateException ex) {

            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);


        }
```

result : website.com/find?name=Arnar+A%f0alsteinsson

Comment: I've created an example windows form application that works correctly as expected.

    string name = "Arnar Aðalsteinsson";
    string encodedName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
    string url = string.Format("https://www.website.com/find?name={1}", session, encodedName);
    string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

This just does not reflect what happens in Xamarin Android.